# Reverse edge map for boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to use boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow to segment an image using the standard technique of starting with a grid graph on the image, and then adding a "special" source and sink node that every grid vertex is connected to.

I have constructed this graph for a 2x2 image (for a total of 2*2 + 2 = 6 nodes) to represent the most basic case, just to try to get the Boost types to agree. I have come up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    boost::no_property,
    boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, std::size_t> > GraphType;

typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_descriptor EdgeDescriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertices_size_type VertexIndex;
typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edges_size_type EdgeIndex;

void AddBidirectionalEdge(GraphType& graph, unsigned int source, unsigned int target, float weight,
                          std::vector<EdgeDescriptor>& reverseEdges, std::vector<float>& capacity)
{
    // Add edges between grid vertices. We have to create the edge and the reverse edge,
    // then add the reverseEdge as the corresponding reverse edge to 'edge', and then add 'edge'
    // as the corresponding reverse edge to 'reverseEdge'
    EdgeDescriptor edge = add_edge(source, target, 1, graph).first;
    EdgeDescriptor reverseEdge = add_edge(target, source, 1, graph).first;
    reverseEdges.push_back(reverseEdge);
    reverseEdges.push_back(edge);
    capacity.push_back(weight);
    capacity.push_back(weight);
}

int main()
{
  GraphType graph;

  unsigned int numberOfVertices = 2*2 + 2; // a 2x2 grid
  std::vector<int> groups(numberOfVertices);

  std::vector<EdgeDescriptor> reverseEdges;

  std::vector<float> capacity;

  float weight = 1;
  AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, 0, 1, weight, reverseEdges, capacity);
  AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, 1, 2, weight, reverseEdges, capacity);
  AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, 2, 3, weight, reverseEdges, capacity);
  AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, 3, 0, weight, reverseEdges, capacity);

  int sourceId = 4;
  int sinkId = 5;
  // Add edges between all vertices and the source, as well as between all vertices and the sink
  float highWeight = 1000;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
      AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, i, sourceId, highWeight, reverseEdges, capacity);
      AddBidirectionalEdge(graph, i, sinkId, highWeight, reverseEdges, capacity);
  }

  std::vector<float> residual_capacity(num_edges(graph), 0);

  VertexDescriptor sourceVertex = vertex(4,graph);
  VertexDescriptor sinkVertex = vertex(5,graph);

  // There should be 2*2 + 2 = 6 nodes
  std::cout << "Number of vertices " << num_vertices(graph) << std::endl;

  // There should be 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 edges
  std::cout << "Number of edges " << num_edges(graph) << std::endl;

  boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(graph,
      boost::make_iterator_property_map(&capacity[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)),
      boost::make_iterator_property_map(&residual_capacity[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)),
      boost::make_iterator_property_map(&reverseEdges[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)),
      boost::make_iterator_property_map(&groups[0], get(boost::vertex_index, graph)),
      get(boost::vertex_index, graph),
      sourceVertex,
      sinkVertex);

  // Display the segmentation
  for(size_t index=0; index < groups.size(); ++index)
  {
       std::cout << "Vertex " << index << " is in group " << groups[index] << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It compiles, but at runtime I get:

```
Assertion `get(m_rev_edge_map, get(m_rev_edge_map, *ei)) == *ei' failed.
```

Can anyone see what is wrong? It is not clear from the documentation exactly what the vector of reverse edges is supposed to look like - is it supposed to be the same length as the number of edges in the graph? Or half that length?

Comment: The assertion is basically `reverse_map[reverse_map[edge]]==edge`. Meaning that every edge needs to be the reverse of its reverse. If I'm not mistaken you fill `reverse_edges` for every edge in your original graph, but never for the reverse ones you create.

Comment: Disclaimer(think!=know):I think [this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb00154d2b16c08) fills the reverse_edges vector correctly but I think the result is not what it should be (but I really have no idea).  I'm not sure about the capacities for the reverse edges, but I **think** they should be 0  if you intend your graph to be directed (like [this one](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/graph_theory_review.html#sec:network-flow-algorithms)) and they should be equal to the one in the original edge if you intend your graph to be bidirectional (like I think should be for an image).

Comment: Ah, I had to set the edge ids manually: 

    int nextEdgeId = num_edges(graph);

    EdgeDescriptor edge;
    bool inserted;

    boost::tie(edge,inserted) = add_edge(source, target, nextEdgeId, graph);
    if(!inserted)
    {
        std::cerr << "Not inserted!" << std::endl;
    }
    EdgeDescriptor reverseEdge = add_edge(target, source, nextEdgeId + 1, graph).first;
    reverseEdges.push_back(reverseEdge);
    reverseEdges.push_back(edge);
    capacity.push_back(weight);
    capacity.push_back(weight);

It runs now! (Now I just have to see if it actually works properly :) ).

Comment: @DavidDoria this question is not related to the original one. Please ask a separate question for this. I think either cv_and_he should post his comments as an answer or you should answer your own question with the last version of the code that resolved your original problem.

Comment: @cv_and_he If you add the modified AddBidirectionalEdge function that I posted in a comment as an answer, I'll accept it (it was your suggestion, after all).

Comment: @DavidDoria I really don't feel confident enough to give an answer. If you have managed to make it work, feel free to make an answer and I'll upvote it(and maybe learn something in the process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to specify the edge index manually. Here is a modified version of AddBidirectionalEdge that correctly constructs the reverse edge map, as well as correctly sets the edge indices.

```
void AddBidirectionalEdge(GraphType& graph, unsigned int source, unsigned int target, float weight,
                              std::vector<EdgeDescriptor>& reverseEdges, std::vector<float>& capacity)
    {
        // Add edges between grid vertices. We have to create the edge and the reverse edge,
        // then add the reverseEdge as the corresponding reverse edge to 'edge', and then add 'edge'
        // as the corresponding reverse edge to 'reverseEdge'
        int nextEdgeId = num_edges(graph);

        EdgeDescriptor edge;
        bool inserted;

        boost::tie(edge,inserted) = add_edge(source, target, nextEdgeId, graph);
        if(!inserted)
        {
            std::cerr << "Not inserted!" << std::endl;
        }
        EdgeDescriptor reverseEdge = add_edge(target, source, nextEdgeId + 1, graph).first;
        reverseEdges.push_back(reverseEdge);
        reverseEdges.push_back(edge);
        capacity.push_back(weight);
        capacity.push_back(weight);
    }
```